# Does SASS support inline IF statements?

Tags: sass, inline

I'd like to set a SASS variable using inline IF's similar to how its done in PHP or Javascript

Is something like this possible?

```
$myVar: ($something >= 10 ? true : false);
```

I'm aware of @if control directives but I want to use a shorter inline syntax.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Sass does support of conditional (ternary) operator or one line if statement as it works in languages like Javascript or PHP.

```
$variable: if(condition, result-when-true, result-when-false);
```

[Article](http://thesassway.com/news/sass-3-3-released#if) about improved if and what's new in Sass 3.3.
P.S. Before Sass 3.3 it did not work as it should. [Issue](//github.com/sass/sass/pull/836) in Sass repo.

Comment: The `if()` function has been around a lot longer than 3.3.  The only difference is that now it is lazily evaluated.