# Sass !default var overrides var set in @if

Tags: sass

I'm building a mixin in Sass 3.4.5, but its not behaving as I would expect, for example:

```
@mixin test($values...) {
  $items: length($values); // length is 2

  @if $items > 1 {
    $var: true;
    @debug $var; // output is 'true'
  }

  $var: false !default;

  @debug $var; // output is 'false', but it should be 'true'
}

@include test(16, 24);
```

For some reason `$var` gets overridden by `!default`, which should not happen.
However, this problem does not happen when I remove the `@if` directive.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCSS change variable out of scope from inside @if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742238/scss-change-variable-out-of-scope-from-inside-if)

Comment: Also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25300453/does-sass-support-inline-if-statements

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for the links, I was able to find a workaround, and sorry for the duplicate. I did search before posting, but guess not hard enough. Voted to be closed.