# How to use default variable if some variable is not there for other theme in scss?

Tags: css, sass, themes, scss-mixins

So I am writing a web app that has themes say light(default) and dark. I am using [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) as per this article [How to Create a Dark Mode in Sass](https://medium.com/@katiemctigue/how-to-create-a-dark-mode-in-sass-609f131a3995). I can create light and dark and also can create multiple themes. But I have to achieve something like this.

Here is the scenario:

I have a question, in the mentioned workaround in the article, What if I do not have `bg: $bg--light,` for dark version and have only for default. like this

```
$themes: (
        default: (
                logo: url("../images/brand/logo_vertical.svg"),
                bg: $bg--light,
                text: $text--light,
        ),
        dark: (
                logo: url("../images/brand/logo_vertical--invert.svg"),
                text: $text--dark,
        ),
);

@mixin themed() {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {
    .theme--#{$theme} & {
      $theme-map: () !global;
      @each $key, $submap in $map {
        $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
        $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
      }
      @content;
      $theme-map: null !global;
    }
  }
}

@function t($key) {
  @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}

.base {
  @include themed() {
    color: t($text);
    background: t($bg);
  }
}
```

This gives an error for no `bg: $bg--light,` in dark. Is there anything that I could do if `bg: $bg--light,` doesn't exist for dark or any other theme it will use of the default one.

Is this possible? how?

Is there any way I can write `if condition` to use the default if a key do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get what you want with a if condition. First, store your default theme in a variable:

```
$default-theme: map-get($themes, default);
```

Then, in your function `t`, check if the key exists with the built-in function [map-has-key](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map#has-key) and use the result to select the desired theme map with a [ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25300554/9718056) operator:

```
@function t($key) {
  $key-exists: map-has-key($theme-map, $key);
  @return map-get(if($key-exists, $theme-map, $default-theme), $key);
}
```